# Dynamic SQL Tables A Good Idea?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I was hoping someone a bit more knowledgeable might be able to help me with the problem I'm facing.

I have a game in which I use rails as the backend for handling a number of tasks, including fetching high scores. In the game users can create their own levels, and other users can subsequently play on said levels. I currently store scores in a table called "scores" in the following way

level_id: the id of the level

user_id: id of the user playing the level

total_score:score the user achieved on that level

Each time a user completes a level the high scores for that level are shown, however the problem I see with this is that I for each level I have to fetch every database entry with the corresponding level_id, then order the entries fetched in descending order by total_score.  I feel as though there is likely a better way to do this, as I currently have to sort every score for each level, which seems repetitive, and also I see that this will likely be slow with a large number  of entries in the table, with the level_id being fetched.

I was wondering if a better approach to this would be to create an table for each level, which would possibly hold the user_id and total_score, and would be ordered by total_score. I feel as though this would cut down on the number of sort procedures that would need to be executed, but am wondering if there is a downside to having a large number of tables in a database in this format, or if there is possibly another way to address this issue?

Thanks,

John

Comment: After a user completes a level, do you want to show a limited number of high scores or all total scores for that level in descending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

Your current design is most likely adequate and using one table per Level would offer few benefits but many headaches.

Basically ActiveRecord is built around a "fixed" schema (it does not change at runtime) and having each model instance occupy its own table is just not going to work. A relative database is not a document store.

You would need batsh*t crazy joins to do pull information from several levels and you would basically have to do every kind of query by hand or write your own ORM.

Most likely what you are looking to do can be done by setting a default order on scores and joining:

```
@level = Level.eager_load(:scores)
              .find(params[:id])
```

However first of all you need to ask yourself if this is *premature optimization*. *Premature optimization* often leads to the wrong answers to the wrong questions.

Comment: Your idea would make sense if it was in a non relational database like MongoDB where you would embed Scores in a Level document. However in a relational database you want to group alike entities in the same table so that you can query it efficiently and not have a complete mess.